# Is this correct code for Wordpress offset?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have done php code for Wordpress offset, please see below.
This code works just fine, but I am wondering is this correct way to do that?

Below you can this part of code for this use.

I tried and it works just fine. I hope this code is ok with Wordpress standards.

```
function hc_get_post_type_items($post_type, $cat = "", $pag_items = 10, $latest_items = "", $isSearch = false, $isPagination = true) {
    global $paged;
    global $hc_wp_query;
    if (!isset($paged)) $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    if (!$isPagination) $paged = 0;
    $arr = array();
    $args = array();
    if ($isSearch) {
        $args = array('s' => get_search_query(),'paged' => $paged);
    } else {
        if (is_tag()) {
            $args = array('post_type' => $post_type,'tag'=>$cat, 'posts_per_page' => $pag_items, 'offset' => $latest_items, 'paged' => $paged);
        } else {
            if ($post_type != 'post') {
                $args = array('post_type' => $post_type, $post_type. '-cat'=>$cat, 'posts_per_page' => $pag_items, 'offset' => $latest_items, 'paged' => $paged);
            } else {
                $args = array('post_type' => $post_type,'category_name'=>$cat, 'posts_per_page' => $pag_items, 'offset' => $latest_items, 'paged' => $paged);
            }
        }
    }

 $arr = hc_get_post_type_items($Y_NOW["post_type_slug"],$cat,(($Y_NOW["pagination_type"] == "pagination_wp" || $Y_NOW["pagination_type"] == "") ? $Y_NOW["pag_items"] : "9999"),$Y_NOW["latest_items"]);

$HC_PAGE_ARR = json_decode(stripslashes($post->post_content));
$HC_SOURCE_PAGE_ARR;
if ($HC_PAGE_ARR === NULL & $HC_POST_TYPE != "page" && $HC_POST_TYPE != "post") {
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'y-post-types', 'posts_per_page' => 999 );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $content = json_decode(get_the_content(), true);
            if (!($content === NULL)) {
                if ($content['post_type_setting']['settings']['slug'] == $HC_POST_TYPE) {
                    $HC_SOURCE_PAGE_ARR = $content;
                    break;
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```